# Angular Material 6 MatTable Not Working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular6

I have a Table that is pulling in data from a SQL Database using RXJS (stores, reducers, etc) and puts the data into a 'smart' container, which finally throws the data in my 'dumb' component where my Table is located.

The data loads inside my table just fine. But when I type in the filter, it doesn't do anything and the table retains the same data as before.

I have tried this with using a separate `dataSource` -- `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<AdminData>();` and initialize it in my `ngOnInit()` -- and the filter works, but there isn't any data in the table. So it seems like I either need to chose between directly implementing the MatTableDataSource on the `@Input()` and not have a filter, or use a seperate `dataSource`. Any help is appreciated.

### TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AdminData } from '../../models/admin.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() adminLoading: boolean;
  @Input() adminData: MatTableDataSource<AdminData[]>;

  displayedColumns = ['fullName', 'loginName', 'defaultPlant'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.adminData.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-form-field id="table-filter" *ngIf="!adminLoading">
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="table-container" *ngIf="!adminLoading">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="adminData">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Full Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.displayUserName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="loginName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Login Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.loginName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="defaultPlant">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Default Plant </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.defaultPlant}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="body-cols"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Versions:**

```
Angular            6.0.3
@angular/cdk       6.2.0
@angular/cli       6.0.7
@angular/material  6.2.0
rxjs               6.2.0
```

Comment: I would recommend AfterViewInit.  The table needs to be rendered first.

I have a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries?file=app%2Fmembers%2Fmembers.component.ts.

Comment: Try having the adminData in constructor